# Observable.of return nothing for pipe in image src

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have made a custom pipe for the image src in my application:

It is being used on selector like this:

```
<img [src]="myobject?.URL | secure" />
```

The code for the pipe is:

```
    import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
    import { Http, ResponseContentType } from '@angular/http';
    import { DomSanitizer, SafeUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
    import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';

    @Pipe({
      name: 'secure'
    })
    export class SecurePipe implements PipeTransform {

      constructor(private http: Http, private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

      transform(url): Observable<SafeUrl> {

        if (//myboolcondition) {
          return this.http
            .get(url, { responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob })
            .catch(err => Observable.throw(err))
            .map(val => this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(URL.createObjectURL(val)));
        }
        else {
          // This is not working and the image src are blank 
// My goal in this else loop is just to return what was there originally // in [src]="myobject?.URL in selector

          return Observable.of(url);

        }
      }
    }
```

The issue I am facing is that the else part of the *if* loop in the code of the pipe is not working and is returning empty response and the image is not rendering for the *else* part.

Can you let me know how to return the same url what was there for *"[src]="myobject?.URL"* when the *else* loop of the condition is met in my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are returning an `Observable` and an `Observable` instance begins publishing values only when you `subscribe` to it.
if you want to use  `observables` directly in your template you need **[`AsyncPipe`](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe)**

> `AsyncPipe` accepts as an argument an observable or a promise, calls
> subscribe or attaches a then handler, then waits for the asynchronous
> result before passing it through to the caller.

**Modified code**

```
  <img [src]="myobject?.URL | secure | async" />
```